# Statistically determining telepathy

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

Let us say we define telepathy as mental awareness of existing physical data without using physical senses. I would like to determine the existence of such ability in a statistically significant way. I am neither a statistician or mathematician so would like to know how proof of the following conditions would be statistically significant:
 
I design a program to randomly generate a number between 1 and 3
 
Chance determination of that number without looking would be 33%

I know there is something called p-value for significance and that 0.05 is considered significant in most accepted peer-reviewed studies so that is the pvalue I want to achieve.

How many correct values in a dataset of 100 numbers will I need to achieve pvalue 0.05?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment)

http://www.aaas.org/aaas-affiliates lists the Parapsychological Association as an affiliate, confirming that the American Association for the Advancement of Science regards parapsychology as a valid field of study, though that doesn't mean they accept it as truth.

Your question is fairly basic (no offense) and could've been asked without the first paragraph. In general, you'd expect 33.33... correct with a variance of 100*(1/3)*(2/3) or 200/9 for a standard deviation of about 4.7. 0.05 requires 2 SDs, so if you got 33.333+2*4.7.. rounded up to 43 or more correct, you'd have 0.05. However, there are many other factors to consider before claiming success.

Comment: True. Anyway, be aware that getting 43 right out of 100 is not an strong result. Furthermore, trying rounds of 100 sets of questions until one of them gives 43 or more right results is not a significant result.

Answer (score 6):

Funny you should ask. In an infamous article published in the *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology*, Bem (2011) did that: he argued that some significance tests achieving $p < .05$ constituted evidence of the existence of psychic powers. Among the many objections critics raised is that extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence; see, for example, the Bayesian approach taken by Wagenmakers et al. (2011). Whatever the exact reason, I think that most psychologists and statisticians (not to mention physicists) would agree that you would be insane to walk away from the Bem study believing that psychic powers are real.

More generally, I'd recommend availing yourself of the voluminous existing literature on parapsychology, particularly experiments like this, before doing your own study. I can't think of a topic less deserving of new research.

Bem, D. J. (2011). Feeling the future: Experimental evidence for anomalous retroactive influences on cognition and affect. *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 100*, 407–425. `doi:10.1037/a0021524`

Wagenmakers, E. J., Wetzels, R., Borsboom, D., & van der Maas, H. L. (2011). Why psychologists must change the way they analyze their data: The case of psi: Comment on Bem (2011). *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 100*, 426–432. `doi:10.1037/a0022790`

Comment: I realize in science the majority of believers accept the results of others without testing it in their own experience and I also realize when dealing with deterministic physical data it is completely rational to so.

Comment: however in the case of consciousness i prefer to test and know myself than simply accept the beliefs of another person's experience.

Comment: Read David J Hand,s book "The Improbability Principle: Why Coincidences, Miracles, and Rare Events Happen Every Day.".  He deals with this issue and many others.  He is a famous British statistician who has published several books and numerous articles on probability and statistics.

Comment: By the way I do not see the logic behind the answer of @barrycarter.

Comment: The paper ["Statistical aspects of ESP" (1940) Journal of Parapsychology](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15143740759494986494) by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Feller) famous statistician also looks interesting. (Though I could not find it online, so have not read it.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22.  William Feller is primarily known for his contributions to probability.  He published a 2 Volume book series on probability theory and is also famous for a version of the central limit theorem which assumes what are called the Lindeberg - Feller conditions.  Although the Feller in your reference could be him, I am not sure because of the middle initial.  If it is him his involvement in parapsychology is a little surprising to me.

Comment: @MichaelChernick to clarify, I believe the paper was tongue in cheek! From [NAS memoir](http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/feller-william.pdf): "An amusing and insightful paper (1940) of Feller’s related to some presumed statistical evidence for [ESP]. Experiments were carried out involving sequences of fair coin tosses ... Feller incisively notes that the standard model of fair coin tossing accounts for such excursions without the extra introduction of special effects like ESP."

Comment: @GeoMatt22 That sounds like Feller.  This may be a little off topic.  Uri Geller a famous psychic was very convincing to the average person.  However good magicians exposed his tricks.  Hand in the book I mentioned the magician James Randi exposed Geller.  I also remember my former professor Persi Diaconis (famous, mathematician, statistician and magician) also used his knowledge of magic to exposed many so-called psychics.  I am not sure but I think Geller may have been one.  I do distinctly remember Geller appearing on the Tonight Show and host Johnny Carson exposed him.

Comment: Carson also was a magician and he knew Geller's tricks.  So he set things up so that Geller would fail.

Comment: @MichaelChernick in the more formal science realm, Randi was infamously called in by Nature in 1988 to do ["experimental design"](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v334/n6180/pdf/334287a0.pdf)! (ungated [here](http://www.badscience.net/wp-content/uploads/benveniste02.pdf).)

Comment: There are recent developments centered around Bem's work that were not mentioned here.  The latest that I am aware of (and still just as controversial as far as I can tell) was a meta analysis on replications of Bem's original work. 

https://f1000research.com/articles/4-1188/v1